# Can we protect domain name by law?

Tags: legal, dns-domain

Some company have domain names worth a million dollar. But sometime they are lost to hackers. So I wonder how can we protect domains by law instead of technology?

Comment: The assignment of domain names under a country-specific TLD are governed by the law of that country. It's up to the country how they want to manage and organize the domains under their TLD. While some countries open up their registration to all, most countries have requirements like a registrant need to be registered business in that country, or needing to have a citizenship, or that they can only register domain names related to their business, etc. So yes, this is already the case that domain names are protected by law; it's just each country has different rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the law in your country and the law in the country the registration company is in. In Europe domain names are subject to the trademark law. So a domain name violating a trademark is a valid reason to go to court.